# Create new pull request locally and submit to master

Tags: git, github

I’ve clone some git repository (master branch) and make some development on it locally 
Now I want to submit it but without the following which I know

> Git add.
>
> Git commit -m “my changes”
>
> Git push origin/master

I want to create pull request, but when I read the docs below it says that 
I should related it to existing branch but there is no branch which I can use currently

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

What should be the workflow now to submit pull request ?
Whether its for new branch or not…

Comment: I don't know exactly what you have in mind here, but your third step should be `git push origin master`.  `origin/master` is a _local_ tracking branch, and you typically would not want to pushing it anywhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - `git push origin master` correct. but how should I create a pull request ? I dont want to submit directly to master

Comment: You do this from the GitHub UI, not locally.  See here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  - but should I've a branch ?

Comment: Since it wirten there "In the "Branch" menu, choose the branch that contains your commits. " and I dont have any branch I checkout the master and modify the code...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - OK thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring your changes into the remote `master` branch via a pull request, and *not* directly, then you don't want to be pushing to the remote `master` branch.  Instead, you may create a local feature branch, and then push that:

```
# from master
git checkout -b my_feature
git push origin my_feature
```

Then, from the GitHub website, navigate to your `my_feature` branch, and follow the instructions for creating a pull request to the `master` branch.  Here is a link to GitHub's documentation for creating pull requests, which you should use at least as a starting point:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

Note that many repositories will bar most users from pushing directly to the remote `master` branch.  So, the `git push` you were trying to do might not work.

Comment: you wrote: "Note that many repositories will bar most users from pushing directly" , how they do that ? to prevent submitting directly to master ?

Comment: The owner of the repo may configure this if he wants to.

Comment: How can you please provide link?